# Why does my s:selectItems throws no such element exception?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I'm getting this error `java.util.NoSuchElementException` when i tried to check one of my checkbox under `h:selectManycheckBox` when i submit the form.

The many checkbox is dynamically populated from the bean. Here is my code.

```
<h:form id="eF">
       <h:inputText id="i" value="#{aklat.suggest}">
            <a4j:support event="onkeyup" action="#{aklat.complete}" reRender="m"></a4j:support>
       </h:inputText>

       <s:div>
           <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{aklat.selectedBooks}" layout="pageDirection" id="m">
                <s:selectItems value="#{aklat.books}" var="_book" itemLabel="#{_book}" itemValue="#{_book}" label="#{_book.bookName}"/>
           </h:selectManyCheckbox>
         <a4j:commandButton value="Add Users" action="#{aklat.fire}"></a4j:commandButton>  
       </s:div>             
</h:form>
```

The weird part is it renders some data output but when i checked the source code. there are no input type checkbox element.

Is something I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your managed bean is request scope...

because you are making an ajax request, you have to enable "aklat.books" to persist its value longer than request but shorther than session scope.

If you have tomahawk between your app libraries you can use savestate like this (put it after the h:form tag) :

```
<t:saveState value="#{aklat.books}"/>
```

if no tomahawk, you can use a4j:keepAlive:

```
<a4j:keepAlive beanName = "#{aklat.books}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you  for the reply. Yes absolutely my bean is in request scope only. i will work on your answer. :))

Comment: By the way what do you mean by " shorter than session scope"?and if i declare my bean as session scope would i get the same error? .:)

Comment: with session scope the data would be available between requests (unless you delete it intentionally). did it work?

Comment: yes its working now. but the beanName must be literal so i change it to beanName="aklat"...many thanks- cheers :))